# SQL group by week include weeks where count is 0

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that groups results by week. However, for some weeks the total is 0 which throws off my chart. Is it possible to add a 0 for weeks there there is 0 reviews?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, 
DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at) AS week FROM "reviews" 
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at) 
ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `generate_series()`:

```
SELECT w.week, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM (SELECT generate_series(min(DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)),
                             max(DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)),
                             interval '7 day'
                            ) as week
      FROM reviews
     ) w LEFT JOIN
     "reviews" 
     ON DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at) = w.week
GROUP BY w.week
ORDER BY w.week;
```